# Error wtih vitamio in android studio. Incompatible types

Tags: android, android-studio, vitamio

I'm using android studio and i have a problem with Vitamio VideoView.

Here is my layout file:

[image]

Here is an error in my class:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. `findViewById` returns a `View` which is a superclass of `VideoView`.

Just add a type cast:

```
mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
```